# Use OBD to check car status

Tags: obd-ii, obd, central-locking

i wanted to know if it's possible to use a cheap OBD scanner connect the car to a computer and see the status of the locking system, if the car is locked or not, i dont want to change or send orders to the car only view status

Comment: There are cheap scanners and cheap scanners... What car? Do you want to do this remotely, because if you are in the car with the computer it seems futile...

Comment: I personally have chevrolet cruze 2012, i want to make sort of a deivce that will connect to the obd wirelessly and tell me the status, isbit possible to make this device compatible for all sorts of cars? Or each car has it own system codes?

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to connect an OBDII scanner that talks Bluetooth to your phone. I typically do this. However if you leave it attached, it does drain the battery...

There are companies that provide "security" systems for high end cars, and these allow remote access for a range of things, however after a friend of mine demonstrated this attack, I wouldn't use one myself:

https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-47485731